# Trying to build a simple Pipe and Filter

Tags: c#, design-patterns, task-parallel-library

I am trying to implement the Pipe and Filter pattern integrating TPL Dataflow within it. I am having issues where not all my results are churned out. For example, i put 99999 items into the pipeline and only 85238 came out.

**EmployeeModel.cs**

```
public class EmployeeModel
{

    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public String FullName { get; set; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return $"FirstName: {FirstName}\nLastName: {LastName}\nFullName: {FullName}\n";
    }
}
```

**IFilter.cs**

```
public interface IFilter<T>
{
    T Execute(T input);
}
```

**AbstractParallelFilter.cs**

```
public abstract class AbstractParallelFilter<T> : IFilter<T>
{
    public AbstractParallelFilter()
    {
        TransformBlock = new TransformBlock<T, T>(new Func<T, T>(Execute), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
             BoundedCapacity = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded,
             MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount

        });
    }


    public abstract T Execute(T input);

    internal TransformBlock<T, T> TransformBlock { get; private set; }
}
```

**IParallelPipeline.cs**

```
public interface IParallelPipeline<T>
{

    IParallelPipeline<T> Register(AbstractParallelFilter<T> filter);

    IParallelPipeline<T> CompleteRegisteration();

    IParallelPipeline<T> Process(T input);

    Task CompleteProcessing();


    ConcurrentBag<T> Results { get; set; }
}
```

**AbstractParallelPipeline.cs**

```
public abstract class AbstractParallelPipeline<T>: IParallelPipeline<T>
{

    public AbstractParallelPipeline()
    {
        filters = new List<AbstractParallelFilter<T>>();

        Results = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
    }

    public IParallelPipeline<T> Register(AbstractParallelFilter<T> filter)
    {
        filters.Add(filter);
        return this;
    }

    public abstract IParallelPipeline<T> Process(T input);

    public Task CompleteProcessing()
    {
        if (filters.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("No filters have been registered");

        filters.First().TransformBlock.Complete();

        return filters.Last().TransformBlock.Completion;
    }

    public IParallelPipeline<T> CompleteRegisteration()
    {
        if (filters.Count < 2)
        {
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = filters.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                filters[i].TransformBlock.LinkTo(filters[i + 1].TransformBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
            }

            ActionBlock<T> dumpBlock = new ActionBlock<T>(x => Results.Add(x));
            filters.Last().TransformBlock.LinkTo(dumpBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        }

        return this;
    }

    public IList<AbstractParallelFilter<T>> filters;

    public ConcurrentBag<T> Results { get; set; }
}
```

**ParallelPipeline.cs**

```
public class ParallelPipeline<T> : AbstractParallelPipeline<T>
{
    public override IParallelPipeline<T> Process(T input)
    {
        filters.First().TransformBlock.Post(input);
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<EmployeeModel> employeeModels = new List<EmployeeModel>();
        int count = 99999;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            EmployeeModel employee = new EmployeeModel()
            {
                FirstName = NameGenerator.GenerateFirstName(Gender.Female),
                LastName = NameGenerator.GenerateLastName()
            };
            employeeModels.Add(employee);
        }

        IParallelPipeline<EmployeeModel> parallelPipeline = new ParallelPipeline<EmployeeModel>()
            .Register(new ParallelFirstNameToUpperFilter())
            .Register(new ParallelLastNameToUpperFilter())
            .Register(new ParallelFullNameConcatFilter())
            .CompleteRegisteration();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            parallelPipeline.Process(employeeModels[i]);
        }
        parallelPipeline
            .CompleteProcessing()
            .Wait();


        Console.WriteLine(parallelPipeline.Results.Count);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are registering 3 filters in `parallelPipeline`, what do they do? and what does `NameGenerator` do?

Comment: It just touppers() the property. I just narrowed down the problem.  I need to threadsleep awhile before i enumerate the results. Seems like concurrentbag was not fully ready adding all the items to the list. Is there a way to know if concurrentbag is ready? Or is there a better data structure to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the newbie bug, during CompleteProcessing(), I need to return my ActionBlock instead of my TransformBlock as the ActionBlock is the last block.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to write that as the answer. Hard to spot but nice you found it.

Comment: By the way, having just one filter messed things up. It did not complete at all

Comment: Oh yes! And I wonder why the synchronous one is faster than the parallel one. If you do know why let me know. Else will put up another question tomorrow haha. Thanks for your help man